# How to Inspect Element in Flutter App, How to do the Flutter app Automation

Tags: c#, flutter, selenium-webdriver, shadow-dom

I am having a QA Automation framework for an web application using selenium C#.
I'm trying to inspect the elements but it not working. can any suggest how to do automation testing in flutter web application. or suggest any other testing tool support the flutter web application testing.

Please refer below html code:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLdC1.png

Comment: Please don´t add code as image. Add it as formatted text to your question.

Comment: Can you elaborate more, which element are you trying to inspect? In image I can not understand the issue. also you can use selenium for it.

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to see Xpaths using a browser extension.
Search Chrome extension store for various xpath extenstion (I don't know if I am allow to mention details).

Then simply rightclick any element on webpage and choose to see the xpath for the element.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).